# Android - How to make a static ImageView in XML?

Tags: android, static, imageview

Please note that I am not asking about a fixed sized `ImageView` here. By static I mean like:

```
private static ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
```

Now I know that this is the way to do it programmatically, but is there a way to declare a static `ImageView` from XML?

I actually want a part (in this case `ImageView`) of my layout to be common throughout the application.

Comment: How is this going to make my `ImageView` static?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. 
Make a layout with your imageView and reuse that layout using `<include android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/yourlayout" />` in your other xml files.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a Layout file with imageview
2.then use it or inflate it in your activities

Answer (score 0):

Create file **common_image_view.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:src="@drawable/image” />
</FrameLayout>
```

Use this in another layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/common_image_view"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem you want to create a ImageView which you can use throughout your application. You can do this like...

Create a layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imagelayout">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imageName"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now this layout you can inflate in activity directly. or you can also use in another layout xml like..

```
 <include layout="@layout/imagelayout" />
```

Hope this will help you.